# Javascript Text Change Not Changing ID

Tags: javascript

I have an onclick javascript function that's goal is to change the text of a table to something else

```
function functionL1() {
    if (document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = "Text 1" ) {
        var Transfer1 = document.getElementById("B1 ").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = Transfer1;
}
```

This works but I want to make it so the same text only appears once

Unfortunately this doesn't work

```
function functionL1() {
    if (document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = "Text 1" ) {
        var Transfer1 = document.getElementById("B1 ").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = Transfer1;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("A2").innerHTML = "Text 1" ) {
        var Transfer2 =  document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("A2").innerHTML = Transfer2;
    }
}
```

I think this is because after changing `A1` to `B1` the javascript function doesn't recognise that `A1` no longer is Text 1.

Does anyone know a way around this.

Note: Replacing `innerhtml` with `value` doesn't work

Comment: `document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = "Text 1" ` assigns the text to the variable and always evaluates as `true`. You most probably want `==`.

Comment: No that just didn't work at all

Comment: `=` is for **assigning a value to a variable**. `==` or `===` are for **comparing values**.

Comment: The second function will never execute the `else if` part, because the `if` is always true.

Comment: I didn't even check the comments when writing this answer. The comments explain pretty much the same in short lol.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments by @Gerald Schneider,

You're using an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_operators) (`=`) instead of a [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) (`==` / `===`). This is definitely one of your problems.

Another one might be that your cells don't contain just **text** but also some **markup** maybe? If this is the case and you looked over it then the value of `.innerHTML` will be different than the things you see.

There is also a property in JS called `.textContent` <- ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent))

If you replace `.innerHTML` with `.textContent` you should atleast only get the text back without the HTML even tho it might still be different.

Last but not least, 99.9% of all issues are related to something you did not expect to be the output of a function and JS **is** weird in that way.

To be sure that you're getting the correct value use `console.log()` <- ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)) this will log output of variables, functions and pretty much anything else you throw at it in the JS console within Dev Tools (On windows often accessed by <kbd>F12</kbd> and on OSX <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>)

Log the variables and use a [(strict) equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) instead of an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_operators) and tell us what kind of errors you're getting.

One last thing, when using an `if () { ... } else if () { ... }`
block the
`else if () { ... }` will only run when the first `if () { ... }` evaluates to false. Make sure you keep that in mind when thinking about the logic of your program e.g. *Do I want these checks to be linear or asynchronous?*

Hope it helps!